# Ruby on Rails - Show only rows with certain conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a newbee on RoR and wants to know how to select rows from a database. In this case i want to have rows of all players that plays rugby.

```
<% @players.select(:sport).find ("Rugby") do |rugby| %>
  <%= rugby %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You would usually do this kind of logic in your controller. Your view should just be left for rendering data.

Comment: This will be a great place to start - https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-objects-from-the-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this kind of thing in a controller and pass the information to your view layer.

Controller:

```
# We can use a `where` to select all players that have a sport of "Rugby"
@players = Player.where('sport = ?', 'Rugby')
```

View:

```
<% @players.each do |p| %>
  <%= p %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `Player.where(sport: 'Rugby')` also ...

Comment: That's the better way actually. It's been a while since I touched RoR...